# Why do I not get back business names when using MKLocalSearch?

Tags: swift

For example in a MKLocalSearch query, I set the nautral langauge query to: "Coffee". I get several annotations to drop down where coffee shops are, but I only get addresses, despite them landing on a business name / location. What do I need to include in order to retrieve this data?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = address
    request.region = self.mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        if response != nil {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
            for item in response!.mapItems {
                self.plotPlacemarkOnMap(item.placemark)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code for what you have done so far

Comment: @user2893289 ok I added it!